# mongodb date range search issue

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to find the documents which dates are within a range. The range looks like this:

> var start = moment("2015-02-24T00:00:00+01:00").format();
>
> var end = moment("2015-02-25T00:00:00+01:00").format();

```
Booking.find({car_from: {$gte: start, lt: end}});
```

The data is stored as a Date like this:

```
"car_from" : ISODate("2015-02-24T13:00:00.000Z")
```

Why is this returning 0 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with which datatype I was searching with, adding `new Date()` or `moment().toDate()` around the start and end variables worked for me. Both things do the same.

```
Booking.find({car_from: {$gte: moment(start).toDate(), lt: moment(end).toDate()}});
```